# How to create sub document in mongoose? MongoDB, NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to implement an array of comments as a subdocument, in my main document of posts, I am new to js and mongoose, while I tried updateOne, it is working, but it is not working if I use the save parameter, and if I add another comment, the comment is replacing but not adding as another comment. If I am question is dumb, that is because I am very new, please help me out. [image of my document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh1tD.png)

the codes I tried:

this code works, but as I said, whenever the new comment is made, it is replacing:

```
//add comment

router.post("/:id/comment", async (req, res) => {
try {
const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
const comment = await post.updateOne({ $set: { comments: req.body } });
res.status(200).json(comment);
 } catch (err) {
 res.status(500).json("error");
 }
});
```

the save parameter:

```
//add comment

router.post("/:id/comment", async (req, res) => {
try {
const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
const comment = await post.save({ $set: { comments: req.body } });
res.status(200).json(comment);
  } catch (err) {
res.status(500).json("error");
 }
});
```

my model file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
userId: {
  type: String,
  require: true,
},
description: {
  type: String,
  max: 1000,
},
image: {
  type: Array,
},
likes: {
  type: Array,
  default: [],
},

comments: [
  new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      userId: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
      },
      comment: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
      },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  ),
],
```

},

```
{ timestamps: true }
```

);

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

Comment: That's what $set does.  Did you mean to use $push?

Comment: @Joe I don't know what to use, my requirement is to post a comment document as a subdocument in form of an array. can u tell me what am I doing wrong?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong update operator. If you want to add an element to an array use `$push` operator. This will update the array, whereas `$set` will just set the value you are providing, thus overwriting previous values.

Comment: I am not trying to update, I want to post the comment for the first time, I don't know which one to use, I replaced $set with $push in the save instance, but it's not working. Can you tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I reccomend you to specify default value to empty array and then you can always use push operator to add an item, without caring about this being first time or whatever time